# How to send email via mailgun-js and express

Tags: javascript, html, email, express, mailgun

My form.

```
form(action="/contact" method="POST")
          h3 Contact Form
          .form-group
            label.sr-only(for='name') Name
            input#name.form-control(placeholder='Name', type='text' name='name')
          .form-group
            label.sr-only(for='email') Email
            input#email.form-control(placeholder='Email', type='email' name='email')
          .form-group
            label.sr-only(for='phone') Phone
            input#phone.form-control(placeholder='Phone', type='text' name='phone')
          .form-group
            label.sr-only(for='message') Message
            textarea#message.form-control(name='message', cols='30', rows='5', placeholder='Message')
          .form-group
            input.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg(value='Send Message', type='submit')
```

My express route.

```
var express = require('express');
var mailRouter = express.Router();
var Mailgun = require('mailgun-js');

var api_key = '-------------------------------';
var domain = '------------------------------------------------';

var router = function(){

  mailRouter.post('/contact', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);

    var from_who = req.body.email;

    var mailgun = new Mailgun({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});

    var data = {
      from: from_who,
      to: 'wewe99@yopmail.com',
      subject: 'Inquiry',
      text: req.body.message
    };

    mailgun.messages().send(data, function(err, body){
      if(err){
        res.render('error', {error: err});
        console.log("got an error:", err);
      } else{
        res.render('submitted', {email: req.body.email});
        console.log(body);
      };
    });
  });
};


module.exports = router;
```

I am using the sandbox domain of mailgun. I also authorized the email where I should sent the message. There is no error showing on the console and also no logs on req.body. The browser is just infinitely loading. Anyone who can help?

EDIT:
After sometime, browser finished loading and here what it says
http://prntscr.com/cixg3w

Answer (score 0):

```
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});
```